# server url is not working in payumoney payment gateway

Tags: payment, gateway, payu

My code runing test url is perfect working but when i run code in server https://secure.payu.in/_payment and key and slat key is not working

Please help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem but I have figured it out. It's just your merchant ID has not been verified yet so it will be redirecting to the test server even though you have passed https://secure.payu.in/_payment in the payu_base_url. Thanks